# Hidden Markov Models and Viterbi Algorithm: Fair and Biased Die

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, bayesian-network

So following is the problem that I am trying to solve using Viterbi algorithm and HMM:

[image]

Before attempting to write a program, I want to do this problem by hand for the first 3 observations($651$). Based on the question, I understand that:

$P(i | Fair) = \frac1{6} , 1\leq i \leq 6 $

$P( 6 | Biased ) = \frac5{10} = \frac1{2} $

$P( i | Biased ) = \frac1{10} , 1\leq i \leq 5 $

and the transition matrix is

$Fair$ $Biased$

$\begin{bmatrix}
    0.95 & 0.05  \\
    0.1 & 0.9  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

but where should I go from here ?

EDIT: Assume that initially either fair or biased is equally likely($\frac1{2}$) from a "fictitious" state $O$.

I managed to compute the first 4 highest probabilities:  $1 , 0.25 , \frac9{400}, \frac{81}{40000}$ corresponding to $O , B,  B,  B$

**Is this right ?**

Comment: The question doesn't provide the initial state probabilities. i.e. the probabilities of the die for the first toss being loaded or fair. Maybe you should assume they are equally likely. If so, are you then able to do at least the first iteration of the algorithm?

Comment: @Mick In the absence of initial state probabilities, wouldn't stationary distribution be a more reasonable assumption than uniform?

Comment: @A.S. Yes, I thought of that - and it could be best if the given sequence was pulled out of the middle/end of a long set of observations - but I thought to keep it as simple as possible to start with. Presumably, after the computer program is done, you could easily change that initial probability and re-run it.

Comment: Yes, initially either fair or biased die is likely so assume 0.5. This was how previous problems were done in class.

Comment: @MickA updated with my attempt.

Comment: @JennaMaiz I just fixed typos in my final calculation for $\nu_3(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your figures look like you're doing it right. I get the following, skipping the first fictitious state, which is probably not necessary.

Iteration $1$:

\begin{align}
\nu_1(F) &= P(X_1\mid F)P(F) = P(6\mid F)P(F) = \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{12} \\
& \\
\nu_1(B) &= P(X_1\mid B)P(B) = P(6\mid B)P(B) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4} \\
\end{align}

Iteration $2$:

\begin{align}
\nu_2(F) &= P(5\mid F)\max\{\nu_1(F)P(F\mid F),\; \nu_1(B)P(F\mid B)\} = \dfrac{1}{6}\max\{\dfrac{1}{12}\cdot 0.95,\;\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot 0.1\} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{1}{12}\cdot 0.95 = \dfrac{19}{1440} \qquad\qquad [FF]
& \\
\nu_2(B) &= P(5\mid B)\max\{\nu_1(F)P(B\mid F),\; \nu_1(B)P(B\mid B)\} = \dfrac{1}{10}\max\{\dfrac{1}{12}\cdot 0.05,\;\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot 0.9\} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{10}\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot 0.9 = \dfrac{9}{400} \qquad\qquad [BB]
\end{align}

Iteration $3$:

\begin{align}
\nu_3(F) &= P(1\mid F)\max\{\nu_2(F)P(F\mid F),\; \nu_2(B)P(F\mid B)\} = \dfrac{1}{6}\max\{\dfrac{19}{1440}\cdot 0.95,\;\dfrac{9}{400}\cdot 0.1\} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{19}{1440}\cdot 0.95 = 0.002089... \qquad\qquad [FFF]
& \\
\nu_3(B) &= P(1\mid B)\max\{\nu_2(F)P(B\mid F),\; \nu_2(B)P(B\mid B)\} = \dfrac{1}{10}\max\{\dfrac{19}{1440}\cdot 0.05,\;\dfrac{9}{400}\cdot 0.9\} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{10}\dfrac{9}{400}\cdot 0.9 = \dfrac{81}{40000} = 0.002025 \qquad\qquad [BBB]
\end{align}

So I get $[FFF]$ very slightly in front after $3$ iterations.